# Correct Space Width In A TextBox

Tags: textbox

I have an issue where the ML.NET routine called "GetFormattedConfusionTable()" returns a table as a string and does not print it correctly in a TextBox. As you can see below, the columns are not aligned. However the table is printed correctly if it is written in a text file. Is there a way to correct the space width?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The font had to be changed to "Courier Std"

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Any fixed-width/monospace font will do it.